# JavaScript: why cannot I not call parentFunc.parentFunction() from the callee without the 'this' keyword?

Tags: javascript

So I was getting the following error:

```
TypeError: parentRef.parentFunction() is not a function
```

in my callee.

My callee looked sort of like this

```
function callee(parentRef){
  function subRoutine(){ 
    //stuff
    parentRef.parentFunction(params);
  }
}
```

And the caller looked like this:

```
function caller(){
   refToCallee = new callee(this);

   refToCallee.subRoutine();

   parentFunction(prms){
   //other stuff
  }
}
```

Then I realized that I had seen code that changed the caller to have the following line when defining `parentFunction`

```
this.parentFunction = function(){ etc.}
```

What is the `this`keyword doing here. Is it a namespacing thing? More specifically why does my first definition without using the `this.funcName` syntax not work?

Comment: Hard to explain really, `this` is like magic until you understand `this`, "scope" and "closures". I'd suggest you go on Google and look for those terms, there are hundreds of in-depth tutorials. Then I'd say look for "inheritance" and "prototype" tutorials, you're not using `new` right, it's a common misconception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a function like `parentFunction` inside another function like `caller`, there are 3 ways of doing it.

```
function parentFunction() { ... }

var parentFunction = function() { ... };

this.parentFunction = function() { ... };
```

The first declares a function inside the scope of `caller`. It is only usable inside `caller`.

The second declares a local variable that happens to be a function, it is also only callable inside `caller`.

The third declares a property on the `caller` object that happens to be a function. Anyone with a reference to a `caller` object (like in your example) can call it. This is why the `this.parentFunction` is needed for `callee` to be able to use it.

What you have in your original example,

```
parentFunction(prms) { ... }
```

is not proper javascript. It does not declare a variable or a function, nor does it execute any code.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you want a callback like this:

```
function callee(callback){
  //stuff
  callback(params);
}

function caller(){
   callee(callback);

   function callback(prms){
     //other stuff
   }
}
```